# EF6 get tables dynamicly

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 with database first. Trying to display information about each table (`DbSet`), including number of entries.
Eventually, I want to display some (TOP 200) rows of any selected table from my  `DbContext`. I tried to achieve that using reflection without hard-coded specific types.

```
using (MyDataEntities pd = new MyDataEntities())
{
    var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)pd).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

    var tables = metadata.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.SSpace)
        .GetItems<EntityContainer>().Single().BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>()
        .Where(s => !s.MetadataProperties.Contains("Type")
        || s.MetadataProperties["Type"].ToString() == "Tables").ToList();

    // This is working.
    var set = pd.GetType().GetProperty("MyType1").GetValue(pd);
    var theSet = set as DbSet<MyType1>;

    if (theSet != null)
    {
        int count = theSet.Count();     // This is working.
        var rows = theSet.ToList();     // This is working.
    }
          
    foreach (var t in tables)
    {
        dynamic dbset = pd.GetType().GetProperty(t.Name).GetValue(pd);
        int count = dbset.Count();      // This is not working
        var rows = dbset.ToList();      // This is not working
    }
}
```

I am getting exceptions:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:''System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyAppName.MyType1>' does not contain a definition for 'Count''

Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:''System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyAppName.MyType1>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList''
```

Is this even possible what I am trying?

Comment: `var query = dbset as IQueryable;
  var result = query.ToDynamicList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I converted the dynamic value to IQueryable and from there it can be used like a query.

```
foreach (var t in tables)
{
    dynamic dbset = pd.GetType().GetProperty(t.Name).GetValue(pd);
    var query = dbset as IQueryable;
    var result = query.ToListAsync().Result;
                 

    int count = result.Count();      // This is working
    var rows = result.ToList();      // This is working
}
```

Comment: I converted the dynamic value to IQueryable and from there it can be used like a query. Test the code now. Works.